# Reading Text file comma seperated on Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv

I'm trying to read a comma separated text file that looks like the following:

```
2017-10-24,01:17:38,2017-10-24,02:17:38,+1.76,L,Meters
2017-10-24,02:57:31,2017-10-24,03:57:31,+1.92,H,Meters
2017-10-24,05:53:35,2017-10-24,06:53:35,+1.00,L,Meters
2017-10-24,10:45:01,2017-10-24,11:45:01,+2.06,H,Meters
2017-10-24,13:27:16,2017-10-24,14:27:16,+1.78,L,Meters
2017-10-24,15:07:16,2017-10-24,16:07:16,+1.92,H,Meters
2017-10-24,18:12:08,2017-10-24,19:12:08,+0.98,L,Meters
```

My code so far is:

```
LT_data = fopen('D:\Beach Erosion and Recovery\Bournemouth\Bournemouth Tidal Data\tidal_data_jtide.txt');% text file containing predicted low tide times

LT_celldata = textscan(LT_data,'%D %D %D %D %d ','delimiter',',')'
```

Comment: That's fine, a workable example of several lines is just really useful as we can now test your code. Now what's missing is your specific problem... You could read the `fgetl` documentation to learn how to read in a text file, or the `readtable` documentation for delimited files like this... we have no idea if you're getting an error, undesired outputs, or any other specific issue?

Comment: I'm trying read each comma separated value, so that I end up with an output that looks like the following:

Date | time | date | time | value end line
Date | time | date | time | value end line

Comment: similar to an excel table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mixed data types, I'd recommend `readtable`. This will read your data straight into a `table` object without having to specify a format spec or use `fopen`,

```
t = readtable( 'myFile.txt', 'ReadVariableNames', false, 'Delimiter', ',' );
```

Then you can easily manipulate the data

```
% Variable names in the table
t.Properties.VariableNames = {'Date1', 'Time1', 'Date2', 'Time2', 'Value', 'Dim', 'Units'};

% Create full datetime object columns from the date and time columns
t.DateTime1 = datetime( strcat(t.Date1,t.Time1), 'InputFormat', 'yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss' );
```

If you do know the formats, you can specify the `'format'` property within `readtable` and it will convert the data when reading.

Comment: For the 
% Create full datetime object columns from the date and time column
I'm getting the following error:
Error using strcat (line 86)
Comparison is not defined between datetime and double arrays.

Comment: In my example, the `Date1` and `Time1` columns are initially character types... have you imported them as dates or numeric? My above code with the text you posted verbatim works without this error...

Answer (score 1):

This is working perfectly. The formatspec need to be edited.

```
file = 'D:\Beach Erosion and Recovery\Bournemouth\Bournemouth Tidal Data\tidal_data_jtide.txt'
fileID = fopen(file);
LT_celldata = textscan(fileID,'%D%D%D%D%d%[^\n\r]','delimiter',',')
```

Comment: When the code is **so** similar to the code in the question, it's useful to point out what you've actually changed to make it work (and why it was needed) rather than just "here you go"!

Comment: Thanks for the instructions. Edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks. This method is rounding column 5, how could this allow for decimal places?

Comment: and also instead of having 5 26044 x 1 cells, Is there a was to have one cell 26044 x 5?